# Appcelerator - Android open image galley

Tags: javascript, android, image, titanium, appcelerator

When opening the image gallery sometimes the application crash and sometimes it doesn't.
It shows a java exception but no meaningful message.

Does anyone have a idea? I also used intents but cant get it to work.

Thnxs!

Here a sample of my code:

```
Here a sample of my code:
function openGallery() {
var popoverView;
var arrowDirection;

if(Titanium.Platform.osname == 'ipad') {
    // photogallery displays in a popover on the ipad and we
    // want to make it relative to our image with a left arrow
    arrowDirection = Ti.UI.iPad.POPOVER_ARROW_DIRECTION_LEFT;
    popoverView = imageView;
}
var image = undefined;
Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({

    success : function(event) {
        var cropRect = event.cropRect;
        image = event.media;

        // set image view
        Ti.API.debug('Our type was: ' + event.mediaType);
        if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {
            addAttachment(image);
        } else {
            // is this necessary?
        }
    },
    cancel : function() {

    },
    error : function(error) {
    },
    allowEditing : true,
    saveToPhotoGallery : true,
    popoverView : popoverView,
    arrowDirection : arrowDirection,
    mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:"Accessing the photo album",
    backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF",
    exitOnClose:true
});

var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:"Open the photo gallery",
    width:180,
    height:48,
    bottom: 12,
    zIndex:2
});

button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    //Open the photo gallery
    Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
        //function to call upon successful load of the gallery
        success:function(e){
            //e.media represents the photo or video
            var imageView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
                image:e.media,
                width:320,
                height:480,
                top:12,
                zIndex:1
            });

            win.add(imageView);
        },
        error:function(e){
            alert("There was an error");
        },
        cancel:function(e){
            alert("The photo gallery was cancelled");
        },
        //Allow editing of media before success
        allowEditing:true,
        //Media types to allow
        mediaTypes:[Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
        //The other is Titanium.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
    });
});

win.add(button);

win.open();
```